# Integrating with dynamic clients

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, message-queue

I have an architectural design question. Our company recently brought a COTS (.NET based product) for Case management. This product has a sophisticated Integration module that spits out an full case information XML on to a MQ on every user action. Each XML element have a Add, Edit & Delete flags to know what element got changed.

We have to write an application that processes these events sequentially as they come in and send to multiple external partners conditionally on what got changed. Interface with each external partner is distinct in terms of what data they need, representations (XML, String, json, etc) and protocols (SOAP, REST, MQ, DB-call, etc.).

Any suggestions on how would someone design a system like this and what technologies can be used? (FYI, Our existing technology stack Java/JEE, Weblogic).

PS.
The primary problem that I had with this is, if one of the partner is down we shouldn't hold back on other partners. At the same time no partner should be loosing even a single notification.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach:

[image]

- COTS put messages about application events into the Message Queue.
- A message generator component listens to the message queue and queries a Partner DB about currently known partners. For each COTS message, a event message will be generated for each partner informing about what happened. The event will also have a "delivered" flag. So basically, you transform the message queue filled by COTS to N message queues, one for each partner. Your events should be immutable objects, you could store them within a relational DB or NoSQL DB ("Message DB" in the picture).
- You have N or less endpoint components running within your application server. When they arrive a request, they will ask a common component ("Common Data Retrieval Concerns" in the picture) for new messages.
  The common component queries the message DB, hands over messages as java object list, and the endpoint component cares about serialization.
  The common component could also care about authorization, using information from the Partner DB.

**Attention:** The common component should only flag messages as published, if they were successfully delivered. You might event want to wait for an acknowledgement coming from a partner component.
As you can not guarantee transactional atomicy during that process, your partner clients need to be robust against duplicates.
Your server software as well as each client should manage a message ID (UUID) for each event:

- Your job is to care about generating a unique ID per event message
- The job of your partners is maintaining a lookup table to check whether they already processed an evenet with a certain ID.